# How do I do this query on codeigniter framework?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm kind of new on codeigniter, hope you can help me.

I have a sql query below, how would it look like on codeigniter framework?

```
SELECT m.conversation_id, count(m.message_id)
FROM cms_conversations__messages AS m
LEFT JOIN cms_conversations__participants AS p ON p.conversation_id = m.conversation_id AND (p.last_read IS NULL OR m.added > p.last_read) AND m.user_id != 2
WHERE p.user_id = 2
GROUP BY p.user_id
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are sure that your query is right then this is the codeigniter way to do it**

```
$this->db->select('m.conversation_id, count(m.message_id) as message_count');
$this->db->from('cms_conversations__messages as m');
$this->db->join('cms_conversations__participants as p', 'p.conversation_id = m.conversation_id and (p.last_read IS NULL OR m.added > p.last_read) and m.user_id != 2', 'left');
$this->db->where('p.user_id', '2');
$this->db->group_by('p.user_id');
return $this->db->get()->result(); //  or you can also store it in a variable
```

For more you can see the documention.
Hope It helps

Comment: Thanks. I was'nt sure about the join, but works like this.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using Query Builder you can regular query using `query()` which supports bound data. ([Documented Here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings))

In your case, it could be done like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT m.conversation_id, count(m.message_id)
FROM cms_conversations__messages AS m
LEFT JOIN cms_conversations__participants AS p ON p.conversation_id = m.conversation_id
AND (p.last_read IS NULL OR m.added > p.last_read) 
AND m.user_id != ? WHERE p.user_id = ? GROUP BY p.user_id";

$id = 2;

$query = $this->db->query($sql, [$id, $id]);

//$query might be FALSE, always check for that before trying to get a dataset 
if($query !== FALSE) 
{
    return $query->result();
}

return FALSE;
```

The data is bound to the two question marks in the `$sql` string which gets supplied as the array (i.e. `[$id, $id]`) in the second argument to `query()`.